# "wmic product call uninstall" EXCEPT for specified criteria?

Tags: windows, batch-file, wmic

I seem to have hit a road block on the uninstall portion of a cleanup batch script. I know the actual command is `call uninstall` but I'm using `get name` to try and see if WMIC correctly identifies the programs I need deleted.

I have a list of programs from `wmic product get name` run on a freshly installed PC, and I'm using that as a base and trying to make it uninstall everything that is NOT found on the list.

Here's what I've got so far:

```bash
set /p pl=<"%temp%\product-list.txt"
wmic product where NOT name=%pl% call uninstall
```

I try to test it with `get name` instead, since I don't want to actually uninstall all of my utilities and such that users outside of my department don't need, and there seems to be a sort of syntax error:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>wmic product where NOT name=%pl% get name
name - Invalid alias verb.
```

I'm pretty sure I'm approaching the code incorrectly, I just don't know the correct way to achieve this. Perhaps it's correct, just not compatible syntax with `get name`, but I somehow doubt it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You do know than Win32_Product, (the non aliased name), only lists software which was installed using Microsoft installers, don't you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gotcha here is that the query has to be a single argument. Since you have a space there (between `NOT` and `name=%pl%`), you will have to enclose the whole query in doublequotes, otherwise it will be looked at as *two* arguments. That's why you get the error - because WMIC thinks that `NOT` is the query and `name` would then be a verb like `get`, following the where clause.

```
wmic product where "NOT name=%pl%" get name
```

Just in case you then encounter another error stating it's an invalid query: In this case the issue is that the name string you are comparing with (in the `pl` variable) is not enclosed in single quotes - you could fix that like this:

```
wmic product where "NOT name='%pl%'" get name
```

(Note: Instead of `NOT name='%pl%'`, you could also use `name<>'%pl%'`, but the quotes would still be required, this time not because of spaces but because `<` and `>` would otherwise have special meaning to the shell.)

Comment: I did run into an issue where it seems to only be reading the first line from %pl%.
Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: What do you mean by saying "first line"? Does the product name contain a line break? That's a bit odd. It sounds like you are attempting to do a `NOT IN` query, but that would belong to a separate question, and it would also be good to know where that `pl` variable even comes from.

Comment: ```pl``` is a variable taken from the contents of a text file, which is just the output of ```wmic product get name```. While your solution worked in part, I think I'm looking for something in a FOR loop, and will open another question. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: I feel like this would be much easier in powershell